# Unable to create new event using CalendarKit when following online tutorial

Tags: ios, swift, calendarkit

Please note that I am attempting to add an appointment on an iPhone 13 Pro Max simulator, where I am not able to create a new event using XCode 13.

I have been basing my code on this sample,

https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarApp

The issue is that I am not able to create new events using `CalendarKit`. When I follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iC4XxmExqFA), I get to 13:45 and am unable to create an event. Do I need to add something to my project, like the `Calendar.entitlements` file? Please note that my app is a little different than what is in the video because I am trying to embed the `CalendarKit` calendar into a tab that has been designed in `Main.storyboard` whereas the tutorial indicates that the designer is to be deleted.

So at this point I am only able to create calendar events if I the code directly from https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarApp.git but I have been unable to customize to add it to my own application.

If you wish to view my code you can access it here:

`$ git clone https://github.com/john1726/moor3680_prj.git`

BTW, the issue here [Unable to create new event using CalendarKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898138/unable-to-create-new-event-using-calendarkit/71931517#71931517) has to do with the emulator which has been solved, but this one occurs when I follow the online tutorial on Youtube at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iC4XxmExqFA

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [Calendar View](https://github.com/mmick66/CalendarView) because it allows me to work with `Main.storyboard` UI designer and it also links to Apple's `EventKit`:

```
https://github.com/mmick66/CalendarView
```